# why is this method always returning false even when no error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app in development that allows for premium membership signups with Stripe and, as one would expect, the ability to cancel that membership. In order to cancel membership, users click a button that triggers the `destroy` action in the Promembers_controller.rb. Inside `destroy` there's a call to an instance method `cancel_subscription` that, together with some JavaScript, handles the cancellation of the membership with Stripe, by calling `customer.cancel_subscription`.  Checking my Stripe test records, the memberships are being cancelled, however, it seems as if the method `cancel_subscription` is returning false, because this unsuccessful redirect keeps getting run

```
redirect_to (:back),  :notice => "Not successful. Please try again or contact us."
```

and the rest of the code in the `destroy` action (i.e. after `@promember.cancel_subscription(id)` is not getting run.

Question: (this is borrowed code). Is the cancel_subscription method such that the `false` at the end of the rescue will always be returned (even if there's no rescue taking place) and is that why the redirect in the `else` clause of the destroy action is always getting called? What is a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Promembers_controller.rb

```
    def destroy
        id = current_user.customer_id
        @promember = current_user.promember

        if @promember.cancel_subscription(id)
              session[:pro] = nil

        current_user.customer_id = nil   #is not getting run
        current_user.promember.delete    #is not getting run
        current_user.last_four_digits = nil  #is not getting run
        current_user.save

            redirect_to lawyer_profile_path(current_user), :notice => "Premium membership has been cancelled."

        else 
            redirect_to (:back),  :notice => "Not successful. Please try again or contact us."
        end 

    end
```

Promember.rb

```
def cancel_subscription(customer_id)
      unless customer_id.nil?
        customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(customer_id)
          unless customer.nil? or customer.respond_to?('deleted')          
              if customer.subscription.status == 'active'
                customer.cancel_subscription
                user.remove_role :pro 
                  if user.practices.size > 1                   
                    user.practices.delete(user.practices[1])
                  end               
              end
          end
      end
    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
      logger.error "Stripe Error: " + e.message
      errors.add :base, "Unable to cancel your subscription. #{e.message}."
      false
  end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the `false` at the end of `cancel_subscription` causes an implicit return. Basically, in Ruby, if no return statement is present a method will return whatever the final statement evaluates to. In this case it is equivalent to `return false`. You could try adding a `return true` in an appropriate place like this, since you want to return true any time a delete was successful.

```
def cancel_subscription(customer_id)
  unless customer_id.nil?
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(customer_id)
      unless customer.nil? or customer.respond_to?('deleted')          
          if customer.subscription.status == 'active'
            customer.cancel_subscription
            user.remove_role :pro 
              if user.practices.size > 1                   
                user.practices.delete(user.practices[1])
                return true
              end               
          end
      end
  end
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    logger.error "Stripe Error: " + e.message
    errors.add :base, "Unable to cancel your subscription. #{e.message}."
    false
end
```

Comment: That's not the issue.  The `false` return from the `rescue` block is never executed unless an exception occurs.

Comment: You're right! But if `user.practices.delete(user.practices[1])` isn't returning a true value this might still help.

Comment: That's the real problem.  Implicit return values from nested conditionals get weird.  If you're ever planning to use a return value, it's best to be explicit about it.

Comment: @JimStewart so what is the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Check the return value on `user.practices.delete(user.practices[1])`. If this doesn't return a true/false value you need to explicitly return one as in my example above.

Comment: @brian how do you check what the return value is?  I put `return true` after if `user.practices.size > 1                   
                user.practices.delete(user.practices[1])
              end` and the code works. I didn't put it inside that because sometimes `user.practices.size` won't be `> 1`. The code works now. Just wondering how to check what the return value would be in certain situations.

Comment: Looking at RoR documentation it says nothing about delete returning a false under any circumstances, but it returns a frozen instance on success. Looks like you're OK simply returning a true value since it should raise an exception if it fails. [RoR docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-delete)